# try to solve NSStringEmojize issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ckeditor, emoji

I have ckeditor on my php site to post data from to my app, 
the app does not support emojis and would like to install emojis using NSStringEmojize from this link https://github.com/diy/NSStringEmojize

everything looks great except this error :

[image]

and here is the code

```
   - (void)testFound
{
    NSString *emojiString = @"This comment has an emoji :mushroom:";
    STAssertTrue([[emojiString emojizedString] rangeOfString:@"\U0001F344"].location != NSNotFound, nil);
}

- (void)testNotFound
{
    NSString *emojiString = @"This comment has an emoji :qwertyasdf:";
    STAssertTrue([[emojiString emojizedString] rangeOfString:@"\U0001F344"].location == NSNotFound, nil);
```